# What does "<%= VARIABLE %>" stands for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, devexpress

In DevExpress, I try to understand [a certain component through an example](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/navigation-tab_panel-overview) by decomposing said example.

The markup code contains examples of the following:

`<script type="text/html" id="title"><%= CompanyName%></script>`

Where `CompanyName` stands for a member of a JSON variable.

These are used as input for creating the component, in this fashion:

```
var tabPanel = $("#tabpanel-container").dxTabPanel({
   //other inputs
   itemTitleTemplate: $("#title"),
   itemTemplate: $("#customer")
   }).dxTabPanel("instance");
```

What is the working mechanic behind this? What's the meaning of `<%= var %>` and what does jQuery do when `$("#title")` expression is used?

I need to know this to be able to reprocude the component itself.

Comment: `<%= %>` is a syntax used for HTML templating. I'm not sure what engine it is but it's used to denote that something is a template and needs to be replaced programmatically by a dynamic value.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Its from ASP.Net

Comment: @Satpal thanks. I've never had to use asp.net so I had forgotten the syntax

Comment: Same here, never even seen ASP.NET source code at all, so it was a complete mystery for me.

Comment: I've also used this as a NodeJS expression when passing data from server to client. It could be ASP but just offering an alternative as what it could be

Comment: @wmash In NodeJS, I've never used plain HTML, only Jade templates, not sure if it's compatible with that. Never gone beyond the good old `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = string` method, in fact.

Comment: I should have expanded my answer, I have used the expression using EJS templates in Node and not Jade. It's not an expression with Jade no but could be EJS but (judging by the comments) ASP.net is a more likely reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<%= var %>` is from ERB template language. That embed a string in your HTML code. See more in [API DOCK RUBY](http://apidock.com/ruby/ERB).

JQuery selector `$("#title")` will return the script tag element. [JQuery ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)